# Spring Security 3.2 + Tomcat 6.0.24

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-mvc, spring-security, tomcat6

I'm developing a web application with Spring 3.2.7 and Spring Security 3.2.2

I have a strange problem.

My app is correctly deployed if I use an instance of Apache Tomcat 6.0.35. If I use Tomcat 6.0.24 I don't get static resources! I just receive my welcome jsp but for other resources I always receive 404 error.

Do you know the root cause of this problem? thank you very much!

EDIT: I don't get no error in server log

Comment: Does it work if you aren't using Spring Security? If so, please post your security configuration. Most likely you have added an access rule which denies access to your static resources. There will be an error in the log though, if you have debug logging enabled (which you should).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This most likely means that you have defined the resources folder incorrectly.

Some things to check (which you have most likely done):
1. Ensure you have defined the location of your resource folder
2. Ensure that your src is pointing to the correct location of the resources

From experience:
If all static files are returning 404 then it was the definition of my resource folder location that caused the problem (e.g. calling css/one.css isntead of resources/css/one.css).
If select few static resources then it is very likely your src when calling these files that is incorrect.

Best I can do with information currently supplied. Please include your config setups so that we can help pinpoint better.